# JOOMLA 2.5:Read data from external MSSQL database

Tags: php, sql-server, joomla

In my model file i try to put this code,but does not work.What is wrong?

in php_error.log Fatal error:  Class 'JDatabaseDriver' not found in ...

```
 protected function getListQuery()
    {

        //$db       = $this->getDbo();
        //$query    = $db->getQuery(true);

   $option = array(); 
    $option['driver']   = 'mssql';            
      $option['host']     = '10.10.10.9';    
        $option['user']     = 'lubo';       
          $option['password'] = 'lubo';   
            $option['database'] = 'vladka';      
              $option['prefix']   = '';             
                $db = JDatabaseDriver::getInstance( $option );
                 $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        $query->select('*');
        $query->from('dbo.vyrobky');


        return $query;
    }
```

Comment: I think that `JDatabaseDriver` is not available until Joomla 3, you should try with `JDatabase`

Answer (score 0):

As @Cesar pointed out, class JDatabaseDriver was not present in Joomla 2.5. You have to instance directly the **JDatabaseSQLSrv** class

```
protected function getListQuery()
{
    $option = array(); 
    $option['host']     = '10.10.10.9';    
    $option['user']     = 'lubo';       
    $option['password'] = 'lubo';   
    $option['database'] = 'vladka';      
    $option['prefix']   = '';             
    $db = new JDatabaseDriverSQLSrv($option);
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('*');
    $query->from('dbo.vyrobky');

    return $query;
}
```